# What is wrong with this Wordpress .htaccess configuration?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple website on which I also host a blog in a subfolder `/blog/` and for which I have created the subdomain `blog.example.com`.

Under the root folder `/`, I have a very simple website just displaying info. And in the `/blog/` folder, I have a WordPress blog.

Now, in the root folder I created this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [NC,P]
```

This works fine and when I write `http:blog.example.com` in the browser the Wordpress is displayed and everything works correctly.

However, I would like to activate permalinks in the wordpress, so I activate it in the admin part, and this creates an `.htaccess` in the `/blog/` directory with:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

However, this does not work and I can't understand why. Essentially, what happens is that `http://blog.example.com` works fine, but using the post title after that fails (something like `http://blog.example.com/my-post`).

The address in the url is correct (`http://blog.example.com/my-post`), but what is shown in the browser is the `index.php` of the root folder `/`.

I tried modifying the file doing:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This time I always arrive on the first page of the blog, but it says the post is "not found".

Any idea what the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This may be help to you.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it did not solve anything.  In fact there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

See [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), especially number 9.

> 9. Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says:
>      `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`
>      to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:
>      `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`

If this isn't sufficient, you may also need to modify [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) in `/blog/.htaccess` to

```
RewriteBase /blog/
...
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note `index.php` *without* the leading slash.

Comment: Did not work. Could there be something in the httpd.conf that would block this from working?

Comment: Yes, all configuration files together, httpd.conf, virtual host definitions, and .htaccess, contribute to the configuration.